# I have Integrated Snyk Security Tool with Jenkins I am getting below Issue(I am Using DOTNET Core 3.0 Version project)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, security, jenkins, snyk

[image]

```
FATAL: Snyk Security scan failed.
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred. Could not detect supported target files in C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\ZAPTest.
Please see our documentation for supported languages and target files: https://snyk.co/udVgQ and make sure you are in the right directory.

ERROR: Snyk failed to scan your project. An error occurred. Could not detect supported target files in C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\ZAPTest.
Please see our documentation for supported languages and target files: https://snyk.co/udVgQ and make sure you are in the right directory.
```

Comment: How to [Ask a good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that running a `dotnet restore` command just before running the Snyk scan will resolve the issue

See some guidance here:
https://docs.snyk.io/scan-application-code/snyk-open-source/snyk-open-source-supported-languages-and-package-managers/snyk-for-.net